# Harry Potter and Percy Jackson unite fanfic

Tags: story-identification, harry-potter, fan-fiction, percy-jackson, crossovers

It's about where Dumbledore calls two or three students from each house to help Percy Jackson and Camp Half-Blood in fighting the Titans (so it takes place in The Last Olympian). They gather in Dumbledore's office and start to read the Percy Jackson book series. Also, a Slytherin that attended was a child of Apollo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could this be [Harry and Friends Read The Lightning Thief](https://www.fanfiction.net/s/6019092/1/Harry-and-Friends-Read-The-Lightning-Thief) by Hoff of Slytherin?

Dumbledore summons Harry, Ron, Hermione and a few students from each House to his office:

> I hope I didn't disturb anything important, because I had an urgent letter from a friend in America saying that he needs some Wizarding students to fight in a battle that will be coming up in a few months. I have selected a **few students from each House** that will accompany you on this journey.

There is mention of fighting the titans:

> In the near future, there will be a big **battle against the gods and the titans** and one child of the Big Three gods will make a decision that will either save or destroy Mount Olympus.

Dumbledore reveals the Percy Jackson books:

> "What I have called you all here for today is to learn about these heroes before you go to the camp that is located in America." Dumbledore pulled out a box that consisted of five books. The series was called "Percy Jackson and the Olympians."

And there is a Slytherin student who is a daughter of Apollo:

> "Oh gods," Elaina Troy from Slytherin said. She knew Percy because she was his best mate. If they found out **she was a daughter of Apollo**, Elaina would go ballistic. No one but Draco knew. What if the story mentioned her? Elaina decided that she would tell them after they finished the book.

Comment: Found using `Dumbledore reads Percy Jackson books Slytherin Apollo fanfiction`

Comment: I'll check once I have the time, but I think you got it!